# Getting html data with DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient

I want to get some data from a website but my code can't get url. Because if state is always false and my textbox called "weather1" always display "ece".
When I make the value of textbox as **e.Result** instead of "ece", it displays "**DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs** ".

And there is no error or warning.

What should I do? What's wrong with the code?

```
public void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
           string res = Convert.ToString(e.Result);
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(res);
            var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='tbl_sond']");
            var degree = table.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='renkMax']");
            var date = table.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='sond_zaman']");

        }
        else weather1.Text = "ece";

    }
    public void getWeatherInfo() {
        string url  = "http://www.mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/il-ve-ilceler.aspx?m=ISTANBUL";

        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);


    }
```

Comment: Can you possibly expand this part: `/* some code */`. Also, where in there are you setting the textbox's text to `e.Result`?

Comment: Even after your edit I can't see where `e.Result` is being assigned to the textbox's `Text` property.

Comment: Simon is right, only `weather1.Text = "ece";`, which sets it to `ece`.

Comment: No it's not at my code. I wrote weather1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Result) instead of weather1.Text="ece" .

Comment: `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.Result` is a `string` anyway.. Try using `weather1.Text = e.Result;` and see if that works (although doing what you've done shouldn't cause your issue anyway..).

Comment: My code's problem is can't geting anything about html,not e.result . I said it for clue. I think I did something wrong in getWeatherInfo() but can't find what it is.

Comment: This code worked fine for me; `e.Result` was the HTML of the requested page. What if you made your code synchronous (just use `DownloadString` instead of `DownloadStringAsync`)?

Comment: I add System.Net but it still acts like there is no reference for DownloadString

Comment: For e.Error it gives SecurityException. I'm looking for it now.

Comment: `DownloadString` is a method on the `WebClient` class.